# Problem serializing hashmap with snakeyaml in groovy

Tags: java, jenkins, serialization, groovy, yaml

Problem is when i try to serialize data with snakeyaml it comes out malformed but when i do the same with jsonslurper everything is perfectly formatted.

map is like this

```
gateway_splunky:[appToken:samplekey14124fggfs], MySpaceCredentials:[credentials:[samplekey352453sdffgsdfs, dasklkldsakadsp32525902j5, j6klj65kj45kkj45h, 3hjhjk3h34kjh34k34]]
```

after serialization

```
yamlOutput = new Yaml().dump(map)
```

is equal to

```
gateway_splunky: {appToken: samplekey14124fggfs}

MySpaceCredentials:

  credentials: [samplekey352453sdffgsdfs, dasklkldsakadsp32525902j5,

    j6klj65kj45kkj45h, 3hjhjk3h34kjh34k34]
```

JSON is equal

```
prettyJson = groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(map))


{

    "gateway_splunky": {

        "appToken": "samplekey14124fggfs"

    },

    "MySpaceCredentials": {

        "credentials": [

            "samplekey352453sdffgsdfs",

            "dasklkldsakadsp32525902j5",

            "j6klj65kj45kkj45h",

            "3hjhjk3h34kjh34k34"

        ]

    },
```

Comment: YAML outputs YAML and and SnakeYAML can read JSON.  The JsonOuput can only output JSON. Do you get any errors when reading the YAML back with SnakeYAML or reading the JSON back with e.g. the JsonSlurper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dumpAsMap()`](http://javadox.com/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml.html#dumpAsMap(java.lang.Object)) instead

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.*

Map map = [
    gateway_splunky: [appToken: 'samplekey14124fggfs'],
    MySpaceCredentials: [
        credentials: [
          'samplekey352453sdffgsdfs', 
          'dasklkldsakadsp32525902j5', 
          'j6klj65kj45kkj45h', 
          '3hjhjk3h34kjh34k34'
        ]
    ]
]

new Yaml().dumpAsMap(map)
```

Generates:

```
gateway_splunky:
  appToken: samplekey14124fggfs
MySpaceCredentials:
  credentials:
  - samplekey352453sdffgsdfs
  - dasklkldsakadsp32525902j5
  - j6klj65kj45kkj45h
  - 3hjhjk3h34kjh34k34
```

Comment: Great. In that case you can accept and/or upvote the answer.